# Golang - TLS mutual authentication - Dump client certificates

Tags: go, ssl, server, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I have TLS server with mutual authentication. I want to dump client certificates if handshake error. I use ErrorLog in [http.Server](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) struct, but this logger doesn't get the information about client certificates. I tried to use the VerifyConnection function in [tls.Config](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config) struct, but it starts after the correct handshake. How can I dump the client certificates(wrong and corrects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dump the client certificates through [tls Conn.ConnectionState](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Conn.ConnectionState) after [Conn.HandShake](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Conn.Handshake) as long as the handshake of TLS is done.

Here are code snippets

```golang
    config := tls.Config{
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{yourServerCert},
        ClientAuth:         tls.RequestClientCert,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080", &config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("server: listen err %+v \n", err)
        return
    }

    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("server: accept err %+v \n", err)
        return
    }

    tlsConn, ok := conn.(*tls.Conn)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("server: invalid tls connection")
        return
    }

    if err := tlsConn.Handshake(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("server: client handshake err %+v \n", err)
        return
    }

    state := tlsConn.ConnectionState()
    for _, v := range state.PeerCertificates {
        fmt.Printf("server: remote client cert %+v \n", v)
    }
```